# My hooks are not invoked by Drupal

Tags: hooks

I am developing a module, but the hooks I am adding are not invoked from Drupal. It happens with more than one hook.

I read the documentation for the hooks, and I cannot find anything that would explain why this happens. I verified I am using the correct parameters, and returning the correct value.

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: This question is thought as canonical question for those questions about hooks not being invoked by Drupal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When developing a module, you should keep in mind the following notes.

- The implementation of a hook done from a module is a function whose name is prefixed with the module short name (also called *the machine name*); from the hook name, take off the *hook* part, and replace it with the module machine name. For example, the implementation of [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) done from example.module is `example_menu()`. If the module is example_menu.module, and the function is `example_menu()`, that is not considered the `hook_menu()` implementation for example_menu.module.
  This also means, for example, that the [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) implementation in example_form.module is not `example_form_alter()`, but `example_form_form_alter()`. As another example, the implementation of [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) done for altering the form returned from [`user_register_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_register_form/7) from example.module is not `example_form_user_register_alter()`, but `example_form_user_register_form_alter()`. (The form ID is *user_register_form*.)
- Generally speaking, using uppercase characters in the module machine name doesn't create problems: PHP doesn't make differences between `myModule_get_value()`, and `mymodule_get_value()`, and `$value = myModule_get_value()` would call either `myModule_get_value()`, or `mymodule_get_value()`.
  Although, there is a case where using upper case characters in a module machine name would cause problems: when defining the update hooks for a module. [`drupal_get_schema_versions()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!install.inc/function/drupal_get_schema_versions/7), the function that returns a list of available updates, contains the following code.

  ```
  // Prepare regular expression to match all possible defined hook_update_N().
  $regexp = '/^(?P<module>.+)_update_(?P<version>\d+)$/';
  $functions = get_defined_functions();
  // Narrow this down to functions ending with an integer, since all
  // hook_update_N() functions end this way, and there are other
  // possible functions which match '_update_'. We use preg_grep() here
  // instead of foreaching through all defined functions, since the loop
  // through all PHP functions can take significant page execution time
  // and this function is called on every administrative page via
  // system_requirements().
  foreach (preg_grep('/_\d+$/', $functions['user']) as $function) {
    // If this function is a module update function, add it to the list of
    // module updates.
    if (preg_match($regexp, $function, $matches)) {
      $updates[$matches['module']][] = $matches['version'];
    }
  }
  ```

  The last line executed from `drupal_get_schema_versions()` is the following one.

  ```
  return empty($updates[$module]) ? FALSE : $updates[$module];
  ```

  If the module name is myModule.module, `drupal_get_schema_versions('myModule')` will return just the functions with a name that starts with myModule_update, and ends with a number; functions like `mymodule_update_7120()` will not be included because the regular expression used from `drupal_get_schema_versions()` is case sensitive. This still applies to Drupal 8, as the regular expression is still the same used in Drupal 7.
- Some hooks are called in specific moments. For example, [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7), and [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) are called from Drupal 7 after a module has been enabled/disabled, or when the cache for the router information is cleared; [`hook_init()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) is not invoked for cached pages.
  Once the hooks are invoked because a specific event happened, they will not called again until a similar event doesn't happen. They are not called in two successive page requests.
- Drupal caches the list of hooks implemented from a module. If you are editing the code of an enabled module to add new hooks, you first need to disable and  re-enable the module, or Drupal will not notice there are new hooks.
- Ensure that a `return` statement didn't sneak its way into one of your hook functions during a refactoring. It has the potential to break not only the hook that it appears in, but to cause a chain reaction that breaks other hooks as well, making the problem difficult to locate.

Comment: Also maybe worth to mention my mistake for the sake of others in the future: do NOT define a namespace in your .module (or any other "flat", non-class PHP) file. Otherwise Drupal will not recognize your file, therefore won't discover the hooks defined in them.